Overcoming forces and pressure in SCF step for relaxed slab system
The vc-relax calculation (cell and position optimisation) using quantum ESPRESSO for 2D slab system has printed the end final coordinates and corresponding cell parameters. Using these, the next SCF calculation still shows significant forces and pressure in all directions. Why does it happen? Can we proceed further with such forces and pressure (atleast for slab model)? If not, how to overcome it?

Just a quick check: you're not relaxing all the cell parameters, are you? You don't want to relax the vacuum direction and probably not the cell angles either.

Yes, I am not relaxing the vacuum direction by executing "cell_dofree=c" that fixes c

First, you should know what you are doing. Just because a Quantum Espresso calculation has completed does not guarantee that the simulation you performed is physically accurate.
Second, in the vc-relax step, you can set certain thresholds concerning pressure and forces that need to be met in order for your calculation to finish. These include press_conv_thr and forc_conv_thr. Additionally, you may also reduce the etot_conv_thr if necessary. See the pw.x: input description for more information.
Lastly, to check the quality of your results, it is usually not enough to simply look at your log files. You should use your DFT ground state density to compute further quantities, such as a band structure, to validate your results.
PS:
If you are working on 2D monolayer systems, I suggest you to look up your compound in the Computational 2D Materials Database (c2db) to compare your results against theirs.
